# Incrustar una fuente un pdf existente con itext itext 5 5.5.13.2 pdfbox 2.0.29 para convertitlo en pdfA

Tags: java-8, fuentes, itext, apache-pdfbox

Buenas tengo un problema necesito poder crear un pdfA apartir de un pdf existente y me falla la validación porque existen fuentes no incrustadas dentro pdf
tecnologias que estoy usando
java 8
itext 5 5.5.13.2
pdfbox 2.0.29

este el intne de embeber las funetes no incurstadas

```
 private static byte[] embeberFuente(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        PDType0Font arialFont = PDType0Font.load(document, new FileInputStream(ARIAL_TTF), true);
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            Iterable<COSName> fontNames = page.getResources().getFontNames();
            for (COSName fontName : fontNames) {
                if (!font.isEmbedded() && font.getFontDescriptor() != null) {

                    if (arialFont != null) {
                        page.getResources().put(fontName, arialFont);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        document.save(outputStream);
        document.close();
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

gracias de antemano